# Jquery (1.10.1) menu overlay

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-menu

*Here is my problem in a short form:* I want to have split-buttons with a menu inside (done with jquery-ui see: [jqueryui-demo](http://jqueryui.com/button/#splitbutton), which do **not affect the positioning of anything else**. So the second button should not move at all, if the first split-button shows it's menu, as visibly wrong in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUBqK/2/). I know it would be possible to change the position attribute within the css to absolute, but I really don't want to calculate each position (and recalculate it if something changes or the document.size() changes...

**Is there some way to tell jquery.menu that it should overlay my menu?**

The jsfiddle boils down to the following:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
     $.each($(".key"), convert);

 });

 function convert(index, element) {
     //retrieve button-value
     var key = $(element).text();
     //exchange elements html with the split-button and the menu
     $(element).html(
         '<div><div><button class="KeywordTag">' + key + '</button>
          <button class="selectButton">Options</button></div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="addtoquery">Add to Query</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="opentab">Open in new Tab</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="addtoquerytab">Add to Query in new Tab</a></li>
          </ul></div>');
     //call jquery.button(...) to turn the buttons into good looking buttons the the
     //unordered list into a menu
     //...
     //add event handling
     //...
  }
```

**CSS**

```
//for round borders...
//I'd probably need to change the position attribute, but I really don't want to
//have to calculate each position by hand...
.KeywordTag {
    -moz-border-topleft-radius: 75px;
    -moz-border-bottomleft-radius: 75px;
    -webkit-border-topleft-radius: 75px;
    -webkit-border-bottomleft-radius: 75px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:75px;
    border-top-left-radius:75px;
}
.selectButton {
    -moz-border-topright-radius: 75px;
    -moz-border-bottomright-radius: 75px;
    -webkit-border-topright-radius: 75px;
    -webkit-border-bottomright-radius: 75px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:75px;
    border-top-right-radius:75px;
}
```

**html**

```
<!-- Those spans will be exchanged with 
     the actual buttons and menus by the javascript above -->
<span class="key">examplekey</span>
<span class="key">examplekey2</span>
```

Comment: Your example has an error, please fix.

Comment: sorry, there was a check missing for including jquery-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I solved my problem this morning and I wanted to document the solution for everyone else, I'm answering my own question.

If you define the `<ul>` as `<ul style='position: absolute; z-index=1'>` you get the desired behaviour.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/crapman/VUBqK/7/ or [image: Screenshot with Example]